# Sending image and JSON simultaneously

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I want to pass JSON object and image at the same time from react to my django rest api.

I've tried some solutions from this forum and tutorials but nothing worked in my case. Previously I have been using JSON.stringify on state fields and that worked but i couldn't pass image and now i ended up on something like this.

**postData.js**

```
    let formData = new FormData();
    const { title, description, image, ingredient, step } = this.state;
    formData.append('image', image);
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('ingredient', ingredient);
    formData.append('step', step);
    let conf = {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData,
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    };
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', conf)
    .then(res => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
    })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})
```

**serializers.py**

```
    class RecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      ingredient = IngredientSerializer(many=True, required=False)
      step = StepSerializer(many=True, required=False)

      class Meta:
        model=models.Recipe
        fields=('id', 'title', 'description', 'image', 'ingredient', 'step', )

      def create(self, validated_data):
        ingredient_data = validated_data.pop('ingredient')
        step_data = validated_data.pop('step')
        recipe = models.Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for ingredient in ingredient_data:
           models.Ingredient.objects.create(recipe=recipe, **ingredient)
        for step in step_data:
           models.Step.objects.create(recipe=recipe, **step)
        return recipe
```

**views.py**

```
    class ListRecipes(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
      queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
      serializer_class = RecipeSerializer

    class DetailRecipe(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
      queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
      serializer_class = RecipeSerializer
```

I always get *POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ 400 (Bad Request)* error.

**--EDIT--**

I changed the code and created new endpoint for uploading images and technically it works but I'm trying to append image and created recipe id to FormData() and when I log it to the console it contains both of them but when I'm printing it on the backend it contains only image.

**postData.js**

```
    formData.append('id', this.state.id);
    formData.append('image', image, image.name);

    for(let key of formData.entries()){
        console.log(key);
    }
    let data = {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData,
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        })
    };
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/images/', data)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
```

**serializers.py**

```
  class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = models.Image
       fields = ('id', 'image', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
       print(validated_data)
       recipe = models.Recipe.objects.get(id=validated_data.id)
       image = models.Image.objects.create(recipe=recipe, **validated_data)
       return image
```

Comment: I think it is better if you can create separate endpoints for image and JSON. Then use separate fetch functions for file upload and post JSON.

Comment: Ye I have already thought about it and of course I can do it but to be honest I'm not into DRF that much and I have no clue how to get in that second fetch recipe object which the image should be related to. Can you explain me that or serve link where it is explained?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the DRF [MultiPartParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) to your views' `parser_classes`

Comment: Still the same error. I also added FormParser to parser_classes and `encType="multipart/form-data"` to form and it also didn't work.

Comment: Does the server raise code raise any exception? if it does, please post it

Comment: As i remember it was always giving _Bad request at: /api/_ error. I changed the structure now and I almost got it but i met one problem. I added edit to my question.

Comment: If you debug it, you'll find what causes the bad request. It will be easier to fix by then

Comment: The response received in the client side usually contains details of the error message